ACS 4.18 Secondary storage not showing in UI
I have setuped ACS 4.18.
The issue i am facing is.
the NFS is showing as mounted on the Management server but on the dashboard it its not showing any details, my SSVM and console proxy VM are shown as RUNNING and UP but the VOLUME SIZE shows 0.00 GB
Kindly suggest where i am missing things? is there anythings need to do for Secondary NFS storage to detect in ACS UI?
Thank you, attached the screenshot of ACS dashboard:


Have you added your nfs secondary storage under Infra > Secondary storage for your CloudStack zone? And also is your zone enabled and the SSVM for the zone Up (I.e. agent state is connected)? Also which hypervisor are you using?
